# UserManager value is null for first time to the function FindByNameAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

```
var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
```

I have got the value in `context.UserName` and the same username exists in DB. But `FindByNameAsync()` function returning null sometimes for the first call.

if I call the same function again it is giving output as expected. when I call it as in the below code.

```
if(user == null) {

var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

}
```

Can anyone help me out of this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how is the `context.UserName` value given?

Comment: OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext

Comment: on first call, does `context.UserName` has value? Upon assigning `OAuth...CredentialContext.UserName`?

Comment: Yes, it does have the value.

Comment: This line `var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName)` can only give you null when you passed a username that is not in your database

Answer (score 0):

I get the same time as you , userManager value is null and I solved, here is my solution:

I add this line before using any function of usermanager

```
 var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
 var _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
```

and after i call _userManager

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
```